# How to convert this PHP array into a JavaScript array?

Tags: php, javascript

What would this PHP array look like in JavaScript?

What would be the closest translation?

```
$nursery_rhyme = array(“mary”, “had”, “a”, “little”, “lamb”);
```

Comment: This is not even valid PHP (there are no smart quotes in PHP). Wild guess: copied from your homework?

Answer (score 5):

As others mentioned, the curly/smart quotes are invalid.

You can get the JavaScript representation of most simple PHP structures by running the data through [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)():

```
php> echo json_encode(array("mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb"))
["mary","had","a","little","lamb"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var nursery_rhyme=new Array("mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nursery_ryhme = ["mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb"];
```

Comment: There are no smart quotes in JavaScript. ;-)

Comment: Haha true.  I apparently fail at copy+paste.

I wonder if I should even bother fixing the answer, because off all the other 100% equivalent answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var nursery_rhyme = ["mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest JS translation:

```
$nursery_rhyme = new Array("mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb");
```

Notice:

- no `var` is needed
- you can still use the `$`