# Getting array value from PHP to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

how can i get array value from php to javascript, and use the value for other function in javascript?
here is my source code:

```
<?php
    $sSql  = "SELECT * from contactinfo order by description, nama_cp";
    $r1 = $dbconn->execute ($sSql);
    $idset=array();
    $no=1;
    while (($r1) && (!$r1->EOF)) {
        $s1 = $r1->GetRowAssoc(false);
        $idset[$no]=$s1[id];
        $no++;
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdata(valarray){
    //source..
}
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var line=<?php echo($no); ?>;
     var i;
     for(i=1;i<line;i++){
        $("#action"+i).click(function() {//button, that named with action+int
            //var valarray = ??? -------->value of array idset;
            getdata(valarray);//use data array for other function..
        });
     }
 });   
 </script>
```

in this code, i want to use valarray in function getdata().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
var valarray = <?php echo json_encode($idset); ?>; 
console.log('we got: '+ valarray)
```

When you used alert - you can see the results since it's a json and not test. The best for you will be to use Chrome dev tools (or Firebug on FF) and see in the console the results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use json_encode like in the answer to this question: [How to convert this PHP array into a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479144/how-to-convert-this-php-array-into-a-javascript-array)

If you don't know/don't want to use json, then you just need to think about how php works. It is processed by the server before being sent to the browser, therefore if you want anything in php to be available in javascript you have to print it like so:

```
<?php

$myArr = array();
// add stuff to $myArr
echo '<script type="text/javascript">\n';
echo 'var myJSArr = new Array();\n';
$count = 0;
foreach($myArr as $myItem) {
    echo 'myJSArr[' . $count . '] = ' . $myItem . ';\n';
    $count += 1;
}
echo '</script>\n'

?>
```

Keep in mind if you want to send string values from php to the javascript using the above method you need to print the quotes(") around them as well. You can use your browsers view source to check the generated javascript syntax if its not working.

Comment: i had try it but when i used : alert (valarray[i]); for check the result, it is return "undefined" value..      maybe i used wrong code that i dont know..

Comment: If you know the Javascript syntax, just use your browser's view source to make sure it looks right. I echo the newline character (\n) to print a new line to the source (and not the screen) to make the code look clean. There may be errors in the code I wrote, feel free to post your code if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

`var valarray = <?php echo json_encode($idset); ?>`

Comment: var valarray = <?php echo json_encode($idset); ?>;  
alert (valarray[i]);// check value, but it return "undefined" value.    is there any wrong code i used?